# Cutting numpy array based on index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization

I have a 1D `numpy` array. The difference between two succeeding values in this array is either one or larger than one. I want to cut the array into parts for every occurrence that the difference is larger than one. Hence:

```
arr = numpy.array([77, 78, 79, 80, 90, 91, 92, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104])
```

should become

```
[array([77, 78, 79, 80]), array([90, 91, 92]), array([100, 101, 102, 103, 104])]
```

I have the following code that does the trick but I have the feeling I am being to complicated here. There has to be a better/more pythonic way. Anyone with a more elegant approach?

```
import numpy

def split(arr, cut_idxs):

  empty_arr = []
  for idx in range(-1, cut_idxs.shape[0]):  
    if idx == -1:
      l, r = 0, cut_idxs[0]
    elif (idx != -1) and (idx != cut_idxs.shape[0] - 1):
      l, r = cut_idxs[idx] + 1, cut_idxs[idx + 1]
    elif idx == cut_idxs.shape[0] - 1:
      l, r = cut_idxs[-1] + 1, arr.shape[0]

    empty_arr.append(arr[l:r + 1]) 

  return empty_arr 


arr = numpy.array([77, 78, 79, 80, 90, 91, 92, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104])
cuts = numpy.where(numpy.ediff1d(arr) > 2)[0]

print split(arr, cuts)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One Pythonic way would be -

```
np.split(arr, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(arr)>1)+1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [10]: arr
Out[10]: array([ 77,  78,  79,  80,  90,  91,  92, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104])

In [11]: np.split(arr, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(arr)>1)+1)
Out[11]: 
[array([77, 78, 79, 80]),
 array([90, 91, 92]),
 array([100, 101, 102, 103, 104])]
```

Another with `slicing` -

```
In [16]: cut_idx = np.r_[0,np.flatnonzero(np.diff(arr)>1)+1,len(arr)]
             # Or np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True, np.diff(arr)>1, True])

In [17]: [arr[i:j] for i,j in zip(cut_idx[:-1],cut_idx[1:])]
Out[17]: 
[array([77, 78, 79, 80]),
 array([90, 91, 92]),
 array([100, 101, 102, 103, 104])]
```

Comment: Is there a benefit of using np.flatnonzero instead of np.where?

Comment: @TheDude Nope, `np.flatnonzero` is just more explicit that we are working with 1D arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Another way with slicing, getting the appropriate indices using `np.diff`:

```
import numpy as np
def split(arr):
    idx = np.pad(np.where(np.diff(arr) > 1)[0]+1, (1,1),
             'constant', constant_values = (0, len(arr)))
    return [arr[idx[i]: idx[i+1]] for i in range(len(idx)-1)]
```

Result:

```
arr = np.array([77, 78, 79, 80, 90, 91, 92, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104])
>>> split(arr)
[array([77, 78, 79, 80]), array([90, 91, 92]), array([100, 101, 102, 103, 104])]
```

In your case, your slicing "map" `idx` ends up being: `array([ 0,  4,  7, 12])`, which is where the `diff` is greater than 1 (indices `4` and `7`), padded by a zero on the left, and the length of your array (`12`) on the right using [`np.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html)

But `np.split`, as suggested by @Divakar seems to be the way to go